# How to squeeze buttons in a line?

Tags: button, html, css

I have several buttons in a `<div>`. How can I compact the buttons when the length of the `<div>` is longer than 100%; I mean avoiding the second line?

Something like `scaleX`, but depending on the width of all available buttons.

**Sample Code:**

```
<div class="something">
  <button>some text</button>
  <button>some other text</button>
  <button>another example</button>
</div>
```

**Example:**
http://jsfiddle.net/BRNKt/
I want to make denser buttons (text font) to keep all buttons in the line; but fit within the original div width.

Comment: could you provide some code and/or an image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the rendering more compact by adding `button { padding: 0 }`. You could tweak a little more by adding `.something { word-spacing: -0.3em }; button { word-spacing: 0 }`.

But I don’t see how you could make the font size depend on the available width, which is what seem to mean. (And it could easily lead to serious accessibily problems. Besides, many browsers won’t let you reduce font size below some browser-depedent limit.)

If you can accept line breaks *inside* buttons, i.e. have a button text in two lines, you could “force” the buttons to acceptable width in a manner that makes the text wrap in them, instead of overflowing:

```
button { padding: 0; max-width: 14%; float: left; }
```

However, in that case, it might be better to insert forced line breaks into the buttons, e.g.

```
<button>some<br>text</button>
<button>some<br>other<br>text</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.something,
.something button {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```